# How to programatically restart Node.js app without external dependencies?

Tags: node.js

I want to make the app re-run the command 'node index' after a timeout.

What I tried so far:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    process.on("exit", function () {
        require("child_process").spawn(process.argv.shift(), process.argv, {
            cwd: process.cwd(),
            detached : true,
            stdio: "inherit"
        });
    });
    process.exit();
}, 1000);
```

```
setTimeout(() => {
    process.on('exit', () => {
        exec('node index') // and with absolute path --> exec('node C:\\Users\...')
    })
    process.exit()
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to reinvent something like pm2 or OS-related service management. It's always better to manage such service outside by most convenient tools available on a certain OS.

Comment: I use `forever` as an app monitor and when I want to restart (every morning at 4am), I just call `process.exit()` and forever restarts me.  If I were to do it without forever, I would probably execute a small nodejs script that starts me up in a certain amount of time and then call `process.exit()` on the original process once that detached child process is running.